# How to pass undetermined number of arguments to base constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, arguments

If this is possible at all, what should replace `%PARAMS%`?

```
class ParentClass
{
    public BaseClass( params int[] intList )
    { (...) }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public ChildClass( params int[] intList ) : base( %PARAMS% )
    { (...) }
}
```

*PS.: Sorry if its a newbie question, I just started writing C#.*

Answer (score 1):

Try just

```
public ChildClass( params int[] intList ) : base( intList )
```

See [10.5.1.4 Parameter arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa645765%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> A parameter array permits arguments to be specified in one of two ways in a method invocation:
>
> - The argument given for a parameter array can be **a single expression of a type that is implicitly convertible (Section 6.1) to the parameter array type**. In this case, the parameter array acts precisely like a value parameter.
> - Alternatively, the invocation can specify zero or more arguments for the parameter array, where each argument is an expression of a type that is implicitly convertible (Section 6.1) to the element type of the parameter array. In this case, the invocation creates an instance of the parameter array type with a length corresponding to the number of arguments, initializes the elements of the array instance with the given argument values, and uses the newly created array instance as the actual argument.

So if there is a function:

```
 void Function(params int[] list) {  }
```

it can be called in different ways:

```
Function(0, 1, 2, 3);
Function(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 });
var a = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
Function(a);
ChildClass c = new ChildClass(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this correspond to your needs?

```
class ParentClass
{
    public BaseClass( params int[] ints )
    {  }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public ChildClass( params int[] ints ) : base( ints )
    {  }
}
```

or this:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public BaseClass( IEnumerable<int> ints )
    {  }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public ChildClass( IEnumerable<int> ints ) : base( ints )
    {  }
}
```

Comment: Nop. Actually I want to use indeterminate number of arguments. And it's quite simple indeed. I just asked because it's less intuitive than the usual, and I couldn't find answers to the subject.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain what does `use indeterminate number of arguments` mean?

Comment: Well, probably you know a lot more than me :), but instantiating this class should be something like `new ChildClass(3, 5, 8);`. So that you could use any number of arguments.

Comment: Yes, I tried this right after writing the question, actually. It works.